# How to extract text in python from div tag if other html is within the tag?

Tags: python, scrapy

I am trying to extract a ref. id from HTML with scrapy:

```
<div class="col" itemprop="description">
  <p>text Ref.&nbsp;<span>220.20.34.20.53.001</span></p>
  <p>more text</p>
</div>
```

The span and p tag are not always present.

Using xpath selector:

```
text = ' '.join(response.xpath('//div[@itemprop="description"]/p/text()').extract()).replace(u'\xa0', u' ')
try: 
     ref_id = re.findall(r"Ref\.? ?((?:[A-Z\d\.]+)|(?:[\d.]+))", text)[0].strip()
```

Returns in this case only an empty string, as there is HTML inside the tag.

Now trying to extract the text with CSS selector in order to use remove_tags:

```
>>> ''.join([remove_tags(w).strip()for w in response.css('div[itemprop="description"]::text').extract()])
```

This returns an empty result as I somehow can not grab the item.

How can I extract the ref_id regardless of having html `<p>` tags within the div or not. Some items of the crawl have no `<p>` tag and no `<span>` where my first attempt with xpath works.

Comment: I assume you are aware of the famous [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)? Why aren't you using BeautifulSoup?

Comment: No, never saw that one. I thought scrapy does not need beautiful soup as it can handle tasks like this with css and xpath selectors built in?

Comment: Possibly (I'm not overly familiar with the library), but you're quite clearly throwing the regex module into the mix.

Comment: yes, once I have the text from inside the div, I will use regex to extract the ref id from the text. This works in 90% of the cases, except the ones where there is the additional <span> tag within the text.

Comment: Which is exactly what that answer I linked is trying to illustrate in the general case; don't use regex on HTML, use a HTML parser :)

Comment: Why do you want to extract ID from `div` if you can simply extract it from `span`?

Comment: @Andersson the span tag is not always present.

Comment: You should mention about this in your question and add HTML for both cases (span is present/span is not present)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use the `remove_tags` as you can get directly the `text` with the selectors:

```
sel.css('div[itemprop=description] ::text')
```

That will get all inner text from the `div` tag with `itemprop="description"` and later you can extract your information with a regex:

```
sel.css('div[itemprop=description] ::text').re_first('(?:\d+.)+\d+')
```

Comment: This actually helped me, since the remove tags also removed a separator with removing the <p>. Could you please explain more about the way you are using the css selector? I figured that this will return one tag per line wher you later on grab the first one.

Comment: The interesting part here is the `space` between the selector and `::text` which tells the selector to get all the `text` from the inner elements, not only the current one (which would be the `div`). Later the [`Parsel`](https://github.com/scrapy/parsel) function `re_first` checks all the elements and gets the first one that matches the specified regex.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.

Answer (score 1):

Try to remove `::text` from your last expression:

```
''.join([remove_tags(w).strip() for w in response.css('div[itemprop=description]').extract()])
```

But if you need to extract only `220.20.34.20.53.001` from your html, why don't you use `response.css('div[itemprop=description] p span::text').extract()`?

Or even `response.css('div[itemprop=description]').re(r'([\.\d]+)')`.

Comment: Thank you! That was what I was looking for. I am not using p span .. as this is only present within 10% of the items and then this would return an empty result.

Comment: Your attempt with the regex is interesting, however your regex returns all numbers and there are more numbers present. Trying to adapt this to my regex returns only a dot: response.css('div[itemprop=description]').re(r'Ref\.? ?((?:[A-Z\d\.]+)|(?:[\d.]+))') Is this the propper syntax? The regex should be OK.

Comment: If you add condition that it should start with number, then it works ok: `response.css('div[itemprop=description]').re(r'(\d[\.\d]+)')`

Comment: In you regexp you should avoid dependency from `Ref.` string as it is in another tag body.

Comment: The ref. is the only common element, the id could look totaly different. I got a result now with this command:  re.findall(r"Ref\.? ?((?:[A-Z\d\.]+)|(?:[\d.]+))",remove_tags(response.css('div[itemprop=description]').extract_first()).replace(u'\xa0', u' ').strip())[0] Do you see any improvement that could be done to this query?

Comment: In my opinion better to split it to variables and do some extra checks, for example, does `response.css('div[itemprop=description]').get()` returns something or None, or does `re.findall(...)` returns non-empty list and etc.